# Kubernetes Ingress path redirection from root to some path

Tags: kubernetes, redirect

I have Ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: ingress
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      location ~ favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
      }
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-headers: content-type, x-att-timezone
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: '*'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-expose-headers: 'x-att-userrole, x-att-userdetails, x-att-userid, xatt-location '
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: 'true'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: 'true'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 10000m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: '6000000'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: '6000000'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: '6000000'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'      
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - st-my-doamin.com
      secretName: ingress
  rules:
    - host: st-my-doamin.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /rootpath/.*
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: someService
                port:
                  number: 80
```

And i want to create redirection like this :

if i go to st-my-doamin.com/rootpath i will be **redirect** to st-my-doamin.com/rootpath/login

i tried to create this redirection and got error :

```
This page isn’t working st-my-doamin.com redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are getting the error "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" follow this [link](https://kinsta.com/blog/err_too_many_redirects/) it helps in clearing this error. Follow this [Link](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/) in redirecting the Path.

Add the below annotation in yaml :

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /get_similarity/$2
```

And add Path as below:

```
  - path: /rootpath(/|$)(.*)
```